# Error: IBMJobFailureError: 'Job failed: Error while executing OpenQASM 3 circuit

Tags: qiskit, programming, qiskit-runtime

I am running my circuit on ibm_osaka backend and it always brings me up this error:

IBMJobFailureError: 'Job failed: Error while executing OpenQASM 3 circuit.'

Does anyone know what is the cause of this error and how should I solve it?

Comment: Could you please add some pieces of your code so we can try to reproduce the error?